# CPP: Getting json.exception.type_error.302 when trying to parse a vector of data to a json object

Tags: c++, json

I have a `vector<unsigned char>` which I'm trying to parse into a json object using nholman json library.

My vector looks like that:

```
{\"username\": \"user1\", \"password\": \"1234\", \"mail\": \"user1@gmail.com\"}
```

and when trying to use the parse method like so:

```
json = nlohmann::json::parse(data);
```

I get this error:

`"[json.exception.type_error.302] type must be string, but is null"`

Now I've also tried to parse the data using a string that I've acquired after pushing the data that is in the vector into a string like so:

```
std::string bufferAsString(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
```

But this results in the same error as well. I've read the documentation of the library ( Here: https://github.com/nlohmann/json ) and looked at the parse section and I can't seem to find anything that is different between my example and his, so why do I still get this problem?

EDIT: I've fixed the problem, it seems that I've passed the data with the key "mail" but used the key "email" to search for the mail when I used the `get` method, remember to check if you use the correct keys because that results in this error which isn't really explaining that much.